# spread json data in one column to multiple columns

Tags: python, json, csv

Using Pandas I have created a csv file which contains data like this (hundred rows):

```
first                            second
{'val1': 'm', 'val2': 'f'}       {'val3': 'm', 'val4': 'f'}
{'val1': 'g', 'val2': 'h'}       {'val3': 'i', 'val4': 'k'}
...
```

Is there any way to replace the current header with the first part of Json data. Its value should be under that column. I mean something like this:

```
   val1    val2   val3    val4
    'm'     'f'    'm'     'f'
    'g'     'h'    'i'     'k'
```

Comment: What would be the values for those columns, are you trying to create a empty data frame  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do that. I'm using `eval` since it seems that the CSV contains string representation of dictionaries. (note that you should be certain that the CSV comes from a safe place and doesn't contain any malicious code - `eval` is problematic from a security perspective).

```
df["first"] = df["first"].apply(eval)
df["second"] = df["second"].apply(eval)

res = pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(df["first"]), pd.json_normalize(df["second"])], axis=1)
print(res)

==>
  val1 val2 val3 val4
0    m    f    m    f
1    g    h    i    k
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets try this,

```
# pre-processing would be required if column value is string literal
from ast import literal_eval

(
    pd.concat([
        df[col].apply(lambda x: literal_eval(x))
            .apply(pd.Series) for col in df.columns
    ], axis=1)
)
```

---

```
  val1 val2 val3 val4
0    m    f    m    f
1    g    h    i    k
```

Comment: My data is in a csv file and it contains more than 10000 rows. So  cannot use the `source_json` part...